# Как подключить БД к WPF?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server

Хотел подключить SQl Server к WPF - Программа запускается и сразу же крашится, но ошибки не выдает.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-Q6S0OSM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Laketych;Integrated Security=true");
            cn.Open();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ShipmentTable", cn);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ShipmentGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Что выдает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База данных:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя самое интересное и смешное, то что я уже писал так же(этим способом) часа 5-6 назад и все работало =)

Comment: Вы коннектитесь не к тому Initial Catalog. Нужный ShipmentDB.

Comment: Да, да) Я с Вами полностью соглсен. Делал в спешке ночью - Initial Catalog=ShipmentDB и Select * from ShipmentTable.